# Springframework Failed to parse configuration class on a controller

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am working on a j2ee project with eclipse, maven and spring. All is going quite fine except a weird and annoying behavior i can't resolve...

Let's begin with the stacktrace :

```
[localhost-startStop-1] WARN org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.lttd.controller.FichiersController]; nested exception is
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/lttd/controller/FichiersController$1.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:172)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4760)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5184)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/lttd/controller/FichiersController$1.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:82)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:77)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:587)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:749)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:313)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:186)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:165)
... 18 more
[localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.lttd.controller.FichiersController]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/lttd/controller/FichiersController$1.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4760)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5184)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/lttd/controller/FichiersController$1.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:82)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:77)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:587)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:749)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:313)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:186)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:165)
    ... 18 more
juin 17, 2015 10:42:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.lttd.controller.FichiersController]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/lttd/controller/FichiersController$1.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4760)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5184)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/lttd/controller/FichiersController$1.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:82)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:77)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:587)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:749)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:313)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:186)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:165)
    ... 18 more
```

After some search on google i found it can be related to a classpath problem, so there is my Build path (can't post pictures ...):

In source folder build path :
    intranetLTTD/src/main/java
    Included : All
    Excluded : none

and my project treeview :

Java Ressources
      - src/main/java
           -com.lttd.controller
                -FichiersController

So it don't seems to be a classpath issue.

I also found on google that the "$1.class" means its an anonymous class... why not but i don't make it from my own, ( i don't even know how to make it for a controller ).

This error is happening when i make any change in my FichiersController ( like declare a variable ) but also when i make any change in a controller i created after my FichiersController, but not in the ones i created before.

I found a workaround to still be able to run the project ( and it's a weird workaround ) : after making a change, i have to change in one of my method of the FichiersController :

```
TypeFichier fileType = TypeFichier.valueOf(fileTypeString);
switch(fileType)
```

to :

```
switch(TypeFichier.valueOf(fileTypeString))
```

Or reverse

```
switch(TypeFichier.valueOf(fileTypeString))
```

to

```
switch(fileType)
```

And in my dispatcher-servlet.xml i have :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.lttd" />
```

I hope i've gave all you need to help me find out whats happening, and how to resolve it. Don't hesitate to ask for further informations.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: source of `FichiersController` please?

Comment: Don't give us all your code, just a snippet of code that reproduces the problem. I deleted your 'answer' because it's not an answer, it needs to be an edit to your question; but because your question is too long already, it can't be added. Pare your question down to the essentials.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you solved it already but I just Had the same problem with strange `$1.class` and for me that was a problem with Eclipse's publishing so I just built my web project with maven and put manually the files into my tomcat folder.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : found the cause of the problem : 
`<context:component-scan base-package="com.lttd" />`
was present in dispatcher-servlet.xml , but also in my spring-security.xml (due to the fact i was learning j2ee spring at the beginning of the project). That's why it created a FichierController$1.  But i don't know why it happens with this class only.

After deleted the `<context:component-scan base-package="com.lttd" />` in spring-security.xml, i don't have the problem anymore.

EDIT:
Finally this did not repaired the error, the error reappeared 3 days later...

Here is the method of the FichiersController i have to edit for a temporarily workaround :

```
    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/fileEditAjax*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody FichierFormObject fileEditAjax(@RequestParam (value="fileName", required = true) String fileName,
                                                    @RequestParam( value="fileType", required = true)String fileTypeString){

        FichierFormObject fileFormObject = new FichierFormObject();
        TypeFichier fileType = TypeFichier.valueOf(fileTypeString);

        //If the error is triggered, i have to change this 'switch(fileType)' to TypeFichier.valueOf(fileTypeString) or reverse
        switch(fileType){
            case FICHE_CONNEXION:
            case DOCUMENT_CLIENT:
                //some processing
                break;

            case PROCEDURE:
                //some processing
                break;

            case MODULEM3:
                //some processing
                break;

            case PRODUIT_CONNEXE:
                //some processing
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        return fileFormObject;
    }
```

But i'm not sure the problem comes from my code...

Hope this edit is the right place to add those information.